# is it possible to retrieve the app/service usage information ( the fee/the money) via api?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Is it possible to retrieve the app/service usage information ( the fee/the money) via api?

I noticed that my current [cf command](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/index.html) 's version is 2.40.0

> API endpoint: https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.40.0)

I checked the api list and cannot find any useful information about my request.

Comment: i want to how much i paid for the services/apps usage which was shown at the bluemix consle page http://i.imgur.com/NlZfhlm.png

Answer (score 2):

Billing information for Bluemix services and application usage is not available through an API; it is only available through the Bluemix console. However, feel free to submit the request on the [IBM Bluemix Ideas](https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas) site for future consideration. Bluemix Project Management reviews the ideas regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Using CF CLI you could use:

```
cf curl /v2/organizations/ORG_GUID/summary
```

to retrieve the org guid you can use

```
cf org <orgName> --guid
```

This provides you information about the number of services and applications, and the memory usage.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply.do you how query out the charge for the app/service usage?

Comment: It is not possible through API, actually it is available only through the Bluemix dashboard